# Trying to create a file in Android: open failed: EROFS (Read-only file system)

Tags: android, file, file-io, filesystems, android-file

This line:

```
final FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(name);
```

results in a `FileNotFoundException` with the message being `/2ozjfFQzwv: open failed: EROFS (Read-only file system)` where "2ozjfFQzwv" is what I passed as the name of the file.

I have tried this with and without the `WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE` permission. How do I create this file for writing?

Alternatively, I just want to be able to give an image to a new activity, and it is too large to serialize it in an extra. Is there an easier way than writing it to a file then reading from it again? All the questions on here seem to be about writing to an SD card, which I don't want to do because many people don't have SD card slots.

Answer (score 97, accepted):

> I have tried this with and without the WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE permission.

There is no `WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE` permission in Android.

> How do I create this file for writing?

You don't, except perhaps on a rooted device, if your app is running with superuser privileges. You are trying to write to the root of internal storage, which apps do not have access to.

Please use the version of the `FileOutputStream` constructor that takes a `File` object. Create that `File` object based off of some location that you can write to, such as:

- `getFilesDir()` (called on your `Activity` or other `Context`)
- `getExternalFilesDir()` (called on your `Activity` or other `Context`)

The latter will require `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` as a permission.

> Is there an easier way than writing it to a file then reading from it again?

You can temporarily put it in a static data member.

> because many people don't have SD card slots

"SD card slots" are irrelevant, by and large. 99% of Android device users will have external storage -- the exception will be 4+ year old devices where the user removed their SD card. Devices manufactured since mid-2010 have external storage as part of on-board flash, not as removable media.

Comment: +1 for getFilesDir(), thank you 
 `new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(getFilesDir() + FILENAME));`

Comment: Old devices? As far as I learned from using my Nexus 7 2013, it does not support an SD card... same goes for Nexus 10, perhaps other Nexi.

Comment: @PawełParadowski: All Nexus series devices have external storage. They do not have removable storage. External storage does not mean removable storage.

Comment: You're definitely right, I should've read your post carefully and thought twice.

Comment: For any other visitors from the future, the explanation provided in the docs is that `getExternalFilesDir` will favor removable storage, but `Environment.isExternalStorageEmulated(File)` can determine if it is simply a mount point for a separate internal partition in API 21+.

Answer (score 17):

try using the permission of WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
You should use that whether there is an external card or not.

This works well for me:

```
path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                Environment.DIRECTORY_MOVIES);
File file = new File(path, "/" + fname);
```

and places my files in the appropriate folder

Comment: `Starting in API level 19, this permission is not required to read/write files in your application-specific directories returned by getExternalFilesDir(String) and getExternalCacheDir(). ` https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

Answer (score 8):

Here is simple sample from [android developer](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal).

Basically, you can write a file in the internal storage like this :

```
String FILENAME = "hello_file";
String string = "hello world!";

FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(FILENAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
fos.write(string.getBytes());
fos.close();
```

Answer (score 6):

Adding

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

in manifest and using same as Martin:

```
path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_MOVIES); 
File file = new File(path, "/" + fname);
```

It worked.

Comment: From dev.android: However, if your app uses the WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission, then it implicitly has permission to read the external storage as well.

Comment: @ilyaEremin - true enough

Answer (score 3):

As others have mentioned, app on Android can't write a file to any folder the internal storage but their own private storage (which is under /data/data/PACKAGE_NAME ).

You should use the API to get the correct path that is allowed for your app.

read [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/index.html) .

Answer (score 1):

If anyone getting this in unit/instrumentation testing, make sure you call `getFilesDir()` on the app context, not the test context. i.e. use:

```
Context appContext = getInstrumentation().getTargetContext().getApplicationContext();
```

not

```
Context appContext = InstrumentationRegistry.getContext;
```

Answer (score 1):

To use internal storage for the application, you don't need permission, but you may need to use: `File directory = getApplication().getCacheDir();` to get the allowed directory for the app.
Or:
`getCashDir();` <-- should work
`context.getCashDir();` (if in a broadcast receiver)
`getDataDir();` <--Api 24

Answer (score 0):

Google have restricted write access to the external sdcard. From API 19 there is a framework called Storage Access Framework which allows you the set up "contracts" to allow write access.

For further info:

[Android - How to use new Storage Access Framework to copy files to external sd card](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36023334/android-how-to-use-new-storage-access-framework-to-copy-files-to-external-sd-c)