# Where is my text file saved?

Tags: android, file-io, android-file

I've created a text file but can't seem to find where it is saved to check whether the data was saved correctly!

This is the code i'm using:

```
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("userAccounts.txt");
ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);   
oos.writeObject(Global.getInstance().userArray); 
oos.close();
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that will work:

```
01-10 23:52:56.864    6076-6076/org.example.jonik E/FileTestActivity﹕ 
    java.io.FileNotFoundException: /userAccounts.txt: 
    open failed: EROFS (Read-only file system)
```

See **[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15711268/56285)** for why not; **you're trying to write to the root of internal storage**.
That answer also suggests alternatives which likely are what you actually need! (See [`getFilesDir()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getFilesDir%28%29) and [`getExternalFilesDir()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getExternalFilesDir%28java.lang.String%29).)

By the way, this is an easy way to check where your `FileOutputStream` is trying write the file (wrap in try-catch):

```
File file = new File("userAccounts.txt");
Log.i(TAG, "Path: " + file.getCanonicalPath()); // -> "Path: /userAccounts.txt"
```

Answer (score 0):

This file is located in `data/data/your.package.name/files/` folder.
You can see this file with DDMS File Explorer on emulator or rooted device.

Comment: My data folder is empty. My device is rooted too