# open Failed:EROFS read only file system android

Tags: android, multithreading, file, audio, io

I am trying to play a sound and record it from a phone's microphone then write it to a file (3gp format).
I used threads from some testing purposes. the problem is I get an error like

```
> caused by libcore.io.ErrnoException: open failed: EROFS (read only file system)
```

though I'm not trying to acess any system files.
I looked around and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15711098/trying-to-create-a-file-in-android-open-failed-erofs-read-only-file-system):

I added both Write/read permissions but still it doesn't work.

Here's the code generating the error:

```
public void startRecording(){

    MediaRecorder mRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
    mRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
    mRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
    mRecorder.setOutputFile(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"xfile.3gp");
    mRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
    try {
        mRecorder.prepare();
        mRecorder.start();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

and the thread blocks:

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
 setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

Thread thread=new Thread(new Runnable()
{
    public void run()
    {
        try 
        {
            genTone();
        } 
        catch (IOException e) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block                                                                                                                                                                                          
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        handler.post(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                playSound();
            }                                                                                    });
    }
});
thread.start();
```

Play Sound Method

```
void playSound(){
        AudioTrack audioTrack= null;
        try{
        audioTrack = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,sampleRate, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, generatedSnd.length, AudioTrack.MODE_STATIC);
        audioTrack.write(generatedSnd, 0, generatedSnd.length);

        audioTrack.play();
        Thread thr=new Thread(new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
                startRecording();
            }
        });
        thr.start();

        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.print(e);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/xfile.3gp"
```

Instead of

```
Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"xfile.3gp"
```

Note that your version probably ends up being

```
/sdcardxfile.3gp
```

rather then

```
/sdcard/xfile.3gp
```

Hence the `read only file system` Error

Comment: oh ok i didn't pay attention to that. thank you. now the file shows up but cannot play it. do you think the problem still in the file or the threads?

Comment: If the file has data in it, then it should be fine and it may be the player. If its size is 0, then it means something went wrong.

Comment: it has data in it. but i dont think its fine because in Matlab its not readable.

Comment: Did you defiantly stop the recording properly? `mRecorder.stop();` The audio file header will not be written correctly if its not been called.

Comment: i know. but i need a timer for that since it should be running for one second. im trying to figure out how to add a timer.

Answer (score 0):

I am commenting to this question very late but am sure I can help someone.

I was developing a call recorder app and had the same bug. I detected the bug on a android 4.4.2. I resolved it by unmounting sdcard. I know this is not the solution. But you may use it too.