# Unable to download txt file from ftp server in Android

Tags: java, android, download, ftp

I'm trying to download from ftp server in my android app but when i create the local file i can't write in.

Here the code:

```
        String servidor = ips[0];
        int reply;
        ftp.setDataTimeout(1000);
        ftp.connect(servidor);
        ftp.login(usuaris[0], pass[0]); // ftp.login( username password)
        //ftp.changeWorkingDirectory(".");
        ftp.setFileType(FTP.ASCII_FILE_TYPE);
        File file = new File("resultat.txt");
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file); 
        ftp.retrieveFile("ARTI.txt", fos);
        fos.close();
```

And when i do this

```
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
```

i have this exception:

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: resultat.txt: open failed: EROFS (Read-only file system)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Trying to create a file in Android: open failed: EROFS (Read-only file system)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15711098/trying-to-create-a-file-in-android-open-failed-erofs-read-only-file-system)

Comment: Add the `android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission to your manifest.

Comment: i have the premission too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you don't have the right directory or file location at the server level.

Comment: Thank's i'solved my problem! The problem was that i create the new file in a unknow location. Now i put this and it works: File file = new File("/sdcard/resultat.txt");