# Android - How to use new Storage Access Framework to copy files to external sd card

Tags: android, android-external-storage, storage-access-framework

I'm implementing a file browser feature in my app. I know how to gain persistent permission for the external sd card using the ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE intent and how to create folders and delete files/folders using the DocumentFile class.

I can't however find a way to copy/move a file to an external sd card folder. Can you point me to the right direction ?

Comment: "I can't however find a way to copy/move a file to an external sd card folder" -- you don't have access to an "external sd card folder", other than perhaps via `getExternalFilesDirs()` (plural) and kin. Are you planning on using the Storage Access Framework to ask the user where to copy things to? If so, use Java I/O to copy from the `InputStream` from your source `Uri` to the `OutputStream` of your destination `Uri`.

Comment: If i use the Java file system I don't have permission to modify the secondary sd card. example: create folder: (new File(path)).mkdir(); doesn't work, but utilizing the new SAF by documentFile.createDirectory(name); (where documentFile is created with DocumentFile.fromTreeUri(context, treeUri)) does work. So what I'm looking for is a way to copy files using using the DocumentsContract API.

Comment: As I noted, get a `Uri` for your original, get a `Uri` for your intended copy, open streams on both, and do the Java I/O. I don't recall a built-in copy or move operation, at least in the current shipping editions of Android.

Comment: that worked very well, thank you!

Answer (score 15):

I have figured it out using lots of examples on SO. My solution for music files:

```
     private String copyFile(String inputPath, String inputFile, Uri treeUri) {
    InputStream in = null;
    OutputStream out = null;
    String error = null;
    DocumentFile pickedDir = DocumentFile.fromTreeUri(getActivity(), treeUri);
    String extension = inputFile.substring(inputFile.lastIndexOf(".")+1,inputFile.length());

    try {
        DocumentFile newFile = pickedDir.createFile("audio/"+extension, inputFile);
        out = getActivity().getContentResolver().openOutputStream(newFile.getUri());
        in = new FileInputStream(inputPath + inputFile);

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int read;
        while ((read = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            out.write(buffer, 0, read);
        }
        in.close();
        // write the output file (You have now copied the file)
        out.flush();
        out.close();

    } catch (FileNotFoundException fnfe1) {
        error = fnfe1.getMessage();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        error = e.getMessage();
    }
    return error;
}
```

Comment: inputPath is ??

Comment: @Tushar, the file you are copying of course