# Unable To Write File Inside Primary External Storage

Tags: android

So I have no external SD card and I want to write the file in the `External` partition of my devices internal storage.

Here is my code:

```
private String filename = "SampleFile.txt";
private String filepath = "MyFileStorage";
File mySensorData = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_MOVIES)
    , filepath);
    String myData = "";

private void FileWrite(String sensorReading) throws IOException {
        if (!isExternalStorageAvailable() || isExternalStorageReadOnly()) {
            try {
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(mySensorData);
                fos.write(sensorReading.getBytes());
                fos.close();

                Toast.makeText(this, "File written to the external storage.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        else {

            Toast.makeText(this, "Unable to read the external storage.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    //external storage discrepancies handler
    private static boolean isExternalStorageReadOnly() {
        String extStorageState = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
        if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY.equals(extStorageState)) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    private static boolean isExternalStorageAvailable() {
        String extStorageState = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
        if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(extStorageState)) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

I am constantly getting the `Unable to read the external storage.` toast and this error on the monitor:

```
W/System.err: Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: EROFS (Read-only file system)
```

Where is the problem?
Thanks.

Comment: try getExternalStorageDirectory() instead of getExternalStoragePublicDirectory. Or Environment.DIRECTORY_MOVIES

Comment: @RandykaYudhistira Doesn't work!

Answer (score -1):

You can't do that you need superuser privilges or root user 
check this post already answered.

[Trying to create a file in Android: open failed: EROFS (Read-only file system)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15711098/trying-to-create-a-file-in-android-open-failed-erofs-read-only-file-system)