# Error opening json file (Read only file?)

Tags: java, android, json

Everytime I run the code I get
java.io.FileNotFoundException: search.json: open failed: EROFS (Read-only file system)

here's the code

```
private static void writeJSearchKey(JSONObject obj) throws IOException {
        //write the searchKey value to the json file
        FileWriter file = new FileWriter("search.json");
        file.write(obj.toString());
        file.flush();
        file.close();
    }
```

and here's where the JSONObejct comes from (just for the sake of Context)

```
private static JSONObject writeJsonFile(String key) throws JSONException {
        //get searchInput string to JSON file
        JSONObject o = new JSONObject();
        o.put("searchKey", key);

        JSONObject newO= new JSONObject();
        newO.put("searchEngine", o);

        String oString= newO.toString();
        Log.d(TAG, oString);
        return newO;
    }
```

Comment: Have you checked to see that the file exists (in your storage)? [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15711098/trying-to-create-a-file-in-android-open-failed-erofs-read-only-file-system) should help.

Comment: Okay, so you're trying to write to a file called `search.json` - but in which directory? I suspect that "the current working directory" isn't writable on Android.

Comment: search.json should be in your root folder of the project directory.

Comment: The json file is located in an Assest folder but when I right clicked to copy the root file path it gave me search.json

Comment: @tomerpacific I have tired moving it to the root folder and It still didn't work, altho I will look in the link you sent

Comment: @ProGamer you mean the com.example.app folder?