# How to make a file

Tags: java

I want to ask about java.
Why in my code, java don't make new file "file.txt"

```
package Com.test;

import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Main 
{
  public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException 
  {
     FileWriter output = new FileWriter("file.txt");
  }
}
```

this is an output

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: file.txt (Read-only file system)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:221)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:108)
    at java.io.FileWriter.<init>(FileWriter.java:63)
    at Com.test.Main.main(Main.java:10)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.duy.android.compiler.java.Java.run(Java.java:115)
    at com.duy.ide.javaide.run.activities.ExecuteActivity.executeDex(ExecuteActivity.java:147)
    at com.duy.ide.javaide.run.activities.ExecuteActivity.exec(ExecuteActivity.java:124)
    at com.duy.ide.javaide.run.activities.ExecuteActivity.access$100(ExecuteActivity.java:45)
    at com.duy.ide.javaide.run.activities.ExecuteActivity$1.run(ExecuteActivity.java:88)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
```

Please explain.....

Comment: _java.io.FileNotFoundException: file.txt (**Read-only file system**)_ Are you running this in an online IDE?

Comment: Your program needs permission to write to the filesystem at the location you're targetting.

Comment: maybe the directory doesn't have permission to write file... try to specify another one, like this: Writer fileWriter = new FileWriter("c:\\somefolder\\file.txt");

Comment: Or is this Android? [Trying to create a file in Android: open failed: EROFS (Read-only file system)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15711268)

Comment: Judging by the stacktrace, it is Android.