# Access all files on android

Tags: android, scoped-storage

I am trying to make a file manager type application and I want to access all files. I know it will need MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission but I am not able to figure out which api should I use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am trying to make a file manager type application and I want to access all files.

I'll recommend you to start from here : [Manage all files on a storage device](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/manage-all-files) (keep in mind [you cannot write internal storage](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15711268/16279195) on a non-rooted device).

> I am not able to figure out which api should I use.

[`MediaStore`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore) might suit your needs (even if your question is a bit generic) , so give it a reading to [Access media files from shared storage](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/media).